# Which is better for PhD level: research project or research topic?

Tags: phd, research-topic

I would like to know which is better for pursuing a PhD regarding the scientific achievement (publications, research skills,...):

1. to accept working in a funded research project that's related to your research experience and interests; or
2. to choose freely your research topic without being restricted to a specific idea (given the acceptance of your advisor).

Comment: ...which is better...[in terms of] scientific achievement...[1)] working in a funded research project that's related to your research experience and interests *or* [2)] to choose freely your research topic without being restricted to a specific idea[?]

Comment: Choosing your own topic allows you to work on the topic of the funded project, so your own topic is better in the sense that it gives you more options. But, what perks does the funded project offer?

Comment: This is a false dichotomy.

Answer (score 3):

**Choose the project for a quicker launch to your career.**

In my experience, the freedom to choose a research topic is an excellent 
learning experience, but it takes time and often involves many false starts. Presumably the pre-defined research project will be quicker to pay off in publications and practical research skills (whatever that means for your field). Choosing your own topic might mean you spend less time during your PhD working on projects that will ultimately pay off in a publication.

That said, perhaps the most important research skill in the long run is identifying and defining a valuable research project.  Mature (i.e. faculty-level) researchers are able to quickly identify fruitful paths forward in research, and it is important to develop this skill eventually. It is not necessary to develop it right from the beginning, however.